# Ce mois-ci / Ce jour-là

Tags: grammaire, démonstratifs, suffixes, trait-d-union

Quelle est la règle pour ajouter un tiret '-' avant un 'ci' ou 'là'. Est-il obligatoire d'employer l'adjectif démonstratif avec la particule "-ci" ?

Je pense à des expressions du style: "ce jour-ci", "cette fois-là", "ce livre-là" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour autant que je sache, on met *systématiquement* un tiret entre un mot et *ci* ou *là*.

Voir le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ci)